# workflow solution which can store files

Tags: .net, workflow

I want to develop application which stores word and pdf files generated during the different stage of project and it is easily searchable when required.

I want this application to have capability to create new project, View project and append multiple files at different stage of project.

Can something similar available ready mate on internet or i can develop one using .net?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if Google Docs would meet your needs.
Easy to develop in .NET as well, with logon security, audits, etc.
My team has done this for a private customer.  It was harder to define the work flow, than to do the actual programming.